# Pine: converting series-integer into integer

Tags: pine-script

I have issues with pine script. I needed to create a function that calculates and returns a value of how many bars I will have to go back in time for further analysis.
The return of this function is of a series integer value.
Then I would like to apply functions like sma, ema, atr etc. to this timeframe defined by the function. This results in an error because these functions can only be applied to integer values but not to series integer values.
I do not find any option to convert integer series into integer.
Do you know how to solve this problem or at least have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this by creating custom functions for your calculations. For example :

```
new_day = change(time("D")) != 0

int len = na

len := new_day ? 1 : len[1] + 1

f_sma(_src, _len) =>
    float _sum = 0
    float _sma = na
    for _i = 0 to _len - 1
        _sum := _sum + _src[_i]
    _sma := _sum / _len

    
ma = f_sma(close, len)
```